# Angular version in App-root does not match that of package.json

Tags: angular

I downgraded Angular to version 8, everything went fine and in the package.json the version is 8.2.0, but when I look from the console, the version is still 14.0.3.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "epg",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44498 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44498 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run epg:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {}
}
```

[image: Angular version with ng version from terminal]

[image: Wrong angular version in my console]

To downgrade I followed the steps below:
`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` 
`npm cache clean` 
`npm install -g @angular/cli@8.2.0`
Did I do something wrong? How can I fix this error? Any tip will be appreciated!

Comment: I presume after the downgrade you completely deleted your auto generated node_modules and build folders and re-installed and re-built everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the changes in global npm package but problem is the existing installed packages are still older version you can downgrade by two way

> 1. delete the node_modules folder and delete package-lock.json file
>    and run `npm install` again.
> 2. if it's a new setup then regenerate the project with `ng new-project` name

personally prefer the second solution if you are setup a new project

Answer (score 3):

You just ran `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.2.0` that downgraded you angular-cli only.

You missed deleting your existing `node_modules` folder, removing the `package-lock.json` if there is one, and you didn't run `npm install` that will re-install all your packages with specified version.

Answer (score 1):

If you downgraded to lower version make sure to clear node modules and cache. you can try following steps:

1. Delete node modules using

> $rm -rf node_modules

2. Delete package-lock.json

> $ rm -rf package-lock.json

3. Clear npm cache.

> $ npm cache clean -f

And then try to install again using

> $npm i